# Как сделать бесконечную анимацию на CSS?

Tags: css

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы после применения анимации на объект в CSS она не повторялась, а зациклилась на том, что в последний раз было применено. Например, в 0% цвет был желтым, а на 25% стал красным, и это необходимо зациклить до бесконечности, чтобы цвет снова не становился желтым.

Comment: @keyframes shake-with-delay, но костыль. Для этого использовать JS надо.

Answer (score 2):

Главное задать direction в оба направления

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```